# Get video frame count HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get video frame count as the [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6Zq/184/)

I have downloaded videoFrame.js from [here](https://github.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame) and located in my website directory.

But while clicking on play the video not playing also getting error like,

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the line `var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');`

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

  <div class="frame">  
  <span id="currentFrame">0</span>
  </div>

<video height="180" width="100%" id="video"> 
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
</video>

<div id="controls">
  <button id="play-pause">Play</button>
</div>


<script>

var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');
var video = VideoFrame({
    id : 'video',
    frameRate: 29.97,
    callback : function(frame) {
        currentFrame.html(frame);
    }
});

$('#play-pause').click(function(){
    if(video.video.paused){
        video.video.play();
        video.listen('frame');
        $(this).html('Pause');
    }else{
        video.video.pause();
        video.stopListen();
        $(this).html('Play');
    }
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jQuery add

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

to the html head.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a call to jquery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```